# Swift JSON error : Could not cast value of type '__NSDictionaryM' to 'NSArray'

Tags: ios, json, swift

when decoding JSON from webservice(API) i get error :

```
Could not cast value of type '__NSDictionaryM' (0x1037ad8a8) to 'NSArray' (0x1037ad470).
```

My Code :

```
var kGetURL = "http://bitnami.local/cscart_demo/api/users"

//var kGetURL = "http://localhost/fendy/getjson.php"

var json : Array<AnyObject> = []

 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    start()
 }

 func getData(data : NSData){
    //error at this line :
    json = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) as! Array<AnyObject>
    //error
    tableView.reloadData()
}

func start(){ 
    var url : NSURL = NSURL(string: kGetURL)!
    var data : NSData = NSData(contentsOfURL: url)!
    getData(data)
}
```

if i change url to http://localhost/fendy/getjson.php, its working so nice.

i get error if my url is http://bitnami.local/cscart_demo/api/users

Response from webservice http://localhost/fendy/getjson.php :

```
 [{"id":"17","Name":"KFC","Message":"awesome"},
{"id":"18","Name":"McDonald","Message":"good"},
{"id":"23","Name":"Burger King","Message":"tasty"},
{"id":"38","Name":"Pizza hut","Message":"yummy"},
{"id":"39","Name":"Steak","Message":"very Delicious"}]
```

Response from webservice http://bitnami.local/cscart_demo/api/users :

```
 {"users":
[{"user_id":"4","user_login":"user_4","is_root":"N","timestamp":"1441608048","user_type":"C","status":"A","firstname":"","lastname":"","email":"fendy.w@mvig.net","company":"","company_id":"1","company_name":"Simtech"},
{"user_id":"3","user_login":"customer","is_root":"N","timestamp":"1441604240","user_type":"C","status":"A","firstname":"Customer","lastname":"Customer","email":"customer@example.com","company":"Simtech","company_id":"1","company_name":"Simtech"},
{"user_id":"1","user_login":"admin","is_root":"Y","timestamp":"1441604240","user_type":"A","status":"A","firstname":"John","lastname":"Doe","email":"robby@mvig.net","company":"Your company","company_id":"0","company_name":null}],
"params":{"page":1,"items_per_page":"10","sort_order":"asc","sort_by":"name","sort_order_rev":"desc","total_items":"3"}}
```

i think it's Style is same, but why not working with url http://bitnami.local/cscart_demo/api/users . anyone can help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The bitnami response starts with a `{` and it is therefore a [JSON object](http://www.json.org), which corresponds to an `NSDictionary`. The other one starts with `[` which indicates an array.

You need to change the type of `json` to `Dictionary<String, AnyObject>`, and deserialize as follows:

```
json = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
```

Comment: if i using json type data NSDictionary? its possible? in tableView CellforRowIndexPath i change : var info : AnyObject? = json[indexpath.row] ?

Answer (score 0):

Your method is casting JSON result to an array. It works fine with the URL that returns an array represented as JSON, but it does not work with the URL that returns a dictionary, not an array, represented as JSON.

Although the "style" of returned values looks the same, the second one is a one-item dictionary. What you probably want is to extract the `"users"` element from it, which is an array.

If you do not know which of the two URLs you are getting, you could try both styles with `as?` cast instead of `as!`:

```
let tmp : AnyObject! = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil)
if let arr = tmp as? Array<AnyObject> {
    json = arr
} else if dict = tmp as? [String: AnyObject] {
    json = dict["users"] as! Array<AnyObject>
} else {
    // Handle an error: the input was unexpected
}
tableView.reloadData()
```

Comment: so, type Data variable json must NSDictionary? i get error while follow your example : 
      if let arr ? Array<AnyObject> { // variable binding in a condition requires an initializer

Comment: @fendy You're right, I forgot to do the assignment. Try it now.

Answer (score -1):

try cache for Serialization

```
        do {
            if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments) as? [String : Any] { // as? data type
                if let otherDict = json["dataKey"] as? [String : Any] {
                    //do something
                }
            }
        } catch {
            // can't json serialization
        }
```

Comment: There's already good answers on this page. Using NSDictionary here is not optimal, better use Swift's dictionary. As explained in other answers...

Comment: just change as? [String : Any]