# ios Swift Could not cast value of type '__NSCFBoolean' (0x10da97608) to 'NSArray' (0x10da97e28)

Tags: ios, arrays, json, swift, nsmutablearray

I'm trying to parse a .json file, but I couldn't finalize it because of this error. How can I avoid this? I searched but I couldn't find it.
Error:"Could not cast value of type '__NSCFBoolean' (0x10da97608) to 'NSArray' (0x10da97e28)."

```
if (Dict["gorsel"] != nil) {
            let gorsel = Dict["gorsel"] as! NSArray;
            self.Image = gorsel[0] as! String as NSString;
            self.ImageInfo = ImageSpecs(width: gorsel[1] as! Int, height: gorsel[2] as! Int);
            self.ImageAvailable = true;
            if (self.Image.lowercased.contains("ö") ||
                self.Image.lowercased.contains("ç") ||
                self.Image.lowercased.contains(" ") ||
                self.Image.lowercased.contains("ğ") ||
                self.Image.lowercased.contains("ş") ||
                self.Image.lowercased.contains("ü") ||
                self.Image.lowercased.contains("ı")) {
                self.ImageAvailable = false;
            }
        }
```

Comment: `Dict["gorsel"]` is a boolean. Make sure your code is following the correct format of the JSON.

Comment: Can you post the json that you are trying to parse?

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32434753/swift-json-error-could-not-cast-value-of-type-nsdictionarym-to-nsarray

Comment: Why are you casting things to `NSString` and `NSArray`? This is Swift. Use Swift types. And why call `lowercased` on `self.Image` over and over? Just do it once. Lastly, please use standard naming conventions. Class names start with uppercase letters. Function and variable names should start with lowercase letters.

Comment: Also, you really should avoid using `as!`. If those values are `nil` or not actually the type you claim, your app will crash. You should safely unwrap and cast those values.

Answer (score 0):

> "Could not cast value of type '__NSCFBoolean' (0x10da97608) to 'NSArray' (0x10da97e28)."

`__NSCFBoolean` is a "boolean" object. The error is raised because you want to force-cast a boolean to an NSArray, which indicates this line is problematic:

```
        let gorsel = Dict["gorsel"] as! NSArray;
```

So we see that `Dict["gorsel"]` is actually a boolean (`true` or `false`), but you are expecting it to be an array.

Either the JSON is wrong or your assumption implied by the code is wrong.

In case you want to handle both the array and boolean cases, you could use `as?` instead of `as!`, so that when the conversion failed, it only returns `nil` instead of crashing.

```
if let gosrel = Dict["gorsel"] as? NSArray {
    self.Image = gorsel[0] as! NSString as String
    // etc.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Error:"Could not cast value of type '__NSCFBoolean' (0x10da97608) to
>   'NSArray' (0x10da97e28)."

means you are **forcefully casting a Boolean to an Array** which means **Dict["gorsel"]** was a **Boolean value** and you **tried to cast** it to **array** which threw exception and crash.

To avoid such crash you should play with keywords **!** and  **?** .

where **! means i'm sure**

**? means i'm not sure**

so as per your code

```
let gorsel = Dict["gorsel"] as! NSArray;
```

you are **sure** **Dict["gorsel"] will be an Array** but what is really was a **Boolean**. So as *@kennytm*

answer best approach would be to

```
if let gosrel = Dict["gorsel"] as? NSArray {
    self.Image = gorsel[0] as! NSString as String
    // etc.
}
```

where you are just **assuming it to be array** and further code is **executed** only **if it got an non nil Array** .